# Laravel - why whereRaw() not accepting pivot column

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel-4

I have a **ManyToMany** relation

**Users controller**

```
public function measurement()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('Measurement', 'users_measurement')->withPivot('value');
    }
```

**Column structure**

```
user_id | measurement_id | value
```

**Search query**

```
->whereHas('measurement', function($q) use ( $from, $to )
        {
              foreach (array_combine($from, $to) as $f => $t) {
                    if(!empty($f) && !empty($t))
                    {
                      $q->whereRaw('( users_measurement.value between ? and  ?)', array($f, $t));

                    }
                }
        })
```

**Error**

```
(select count(*) from `lara_measurements` inner join `lara_users_measurement` on `lara_measurements`.`id` = `lara_users_measurement`.`measurement_id` where `lara_users_measurement`.`user_id` = `lara_users`.`id` and ( users_measurement.value between 154 cm and 168 cm) and ( users_measurement.value between 47 kg and 53 kg))
```

If i use

```
$q->whereRaw('( mesurement_id between ? and  ?)', array($f, $t));
```

works

if is use

```
$q->whereRaw('( user_id between ? and  ?)', array($f, $t));
```

works again

Made these just for a test, but why does it not working with **value column** ?